# How to select multiple Integer data from different columns and merge them into single column of array integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have table as follow in my POSTGRES database

Table name:userDetails

```
column 1: userId (Bigint)

column 2: questionId1 (int) Foreign key:: userQuestions(id)

column 3: answer1 (String)

column 4: questionId2 (int) Foreign key:: userQuestions(id)    |

column 5: answer2 (String)
```

Table name: userQuestions

```
column 1: id(bigint)

column 2: question(String)
```

and i want to select output as follow on the basis of userId,

```
column 1: userId (Bigint)

column 2: questionId's (int [])(questionId1 and questionId2)

column 3: questions (String [])( array of questions from table userQuestions against the the questionId1 and questionId2 )

column 4: answer(String []) (answer1 and answer2 from userDetails table in array of String)
```

please help me to write sql query.

SAMPLE DATA

Tablename :: userDetails

```
|userId         |questionId1        |answer1        |questionId2        |answer2

  abc                 1               "hp"                2               "tommy"
```

Tablename :: userQuestions

```
id          question 

1           "What is brand name of your laptop?"

2           "What is name of your pet?"
```

Expected OUTPUT::

```
userId          questionIds        answers                       questions

 abcd              [1,2]        ["hp","tommy"]              ["What is brand 
                                                              name of your 
                                                              laptop?",
                                                            "What is name of 
                                                             your pet?"]
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @ Gordon i have edited my question and have added some sample data and expected output, can you help  me in writing sql query accordingly

Comment: . . Something is wrong with your data structure.  `UserQuestions` doesn't seem to have a connection to `Users`.  I'm expecting a junction table, with one row per user and per question.

Comment: Yes their is relation @Gordon, the columns questionId1 and questionId2 from table userDetails has foreign key on column "id" of table "userQuestions" which i have mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it differently

```
select d.userid, d.questionid1 || ',' || d.questionid2, d.answer1 || ' ' || d.answer2, 
        string_agg(q.question,',')
from userDetails d
join userQuestions q on q.id = d.questionid1 or q.id = d.questionid2
GROUP BY d.userid
```

Comment: This one worked @Tito Thank you ,it only needs 'GROUP BY d.userid' at the end

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to insert the output in a temporary table, that way you can insert `questionId1` with it's question string and `answer1`, then insert `questionId2` with it's question string and `answer2` to the same columns, and then show the results.

***Edit:***
As you requested here is an example that works in SQL Server (I don't know about POSTGRES, never worked on it)

```
Select t1.userId, t1.questionId1 as questionId, (Select t2.question from userQuestions t2 where t2.id = t1.questionId1) as questions, answer1 as answer into #TempTable from userDetails
UNION ALL Select t1.userId, t1.questionId2 as questionId, (Select t2.question from userQuestions t2 where t2.id = t1.questionId2) as questions, answer2 as answer into #TempTable from userDetails
Select * from #TempTable
```

Don't forget before re-executing the code you'll have to delete the temporary table using `Drop table #TempTable`

I have tried a simillar code on SQL Server 2016 and it's working just fine.

Comment: @ Tonner Maan as i am new to sql can u please share the sql query for it

Comment: @BZT there you go an example in SQL Server, not sure if postgresql uses the same queries but you can edit as you need to achieve your goal, hope it helps